# How to switch SMD part for through-hole part in EasyEDA?

Tags: components, cad

I'm using EasyEDA for the first time. I have about zero experience with CAD. I drew this schematic

[image: schematic]

And generated this PCB layout

[image: PCB Layout]

But I really wanted to use a through-hole DIP package for the ATTiny85, not the SMD part.

Is there any good way to replace the SMD part on the schematic with a DIP part in a way that will minimise the amount of work needed to redo the tracks?

(Any other comments also welcome)

Comment: You want to change the footprint of U1.  You can try googling on that with "footprint" as a keyword (i.e. "change footprint in EasyCAD").  Some CAD packages bind the footprint to a part number (meaning you'll need to change the actual part), some CAD packages let you bind the footprint to a symbol on the schematic.  Either way, you need to have the correct footprint in a footprint library, and you need to have a schematic symbol that matches that footprint's pinout.

Comment: You selected ATTINY85-20SU, that's an SMD package. ATTINY85-20PU is a DIP package.

Answer (score 1):

After googling as recommended in Tim Wescott's comment I find it was easier than I had thought.

The basic process was

- Switch to schematic tab
- Click on the component whose footprint you want to change.
- On the right hand side is now a side-bar with "Component Attributes" and "Custom Attributes". Under "Custom Attributes" is "Footprint" showing `SOIC-8...` You can click in that and type `DIP-8` and press enter to get a pop-up window with a list of matching footprints.
- Clicking on each match gives a picture of each footprint. It also shows how the schematic symbol's pins now relate to the new footprint pads. This seems to be done automatically, perhaps by matching pin numbers.
- You can select a suitable footprint.
- Save the file
- Switch to the PCB view
- From the Design menu select Import changes
- You then have to reconnect the tracks by dragging the control points on them.

I didn't have to do anything in the schematic to reconnect nets etc. Reconnecting the tracks in the PCB view was less work than I thought.

As Mat commented, the problem was in me selecting the wrong part number in the first place, The default library in EasyEDA only had SOIC and QFP parts for the ATTiny85. To do this right next time, I will find out how to add new parts to the library.

Comment: When you search the ATTINY85-20SU in the library, click on Edit, then change the name to the DIP part, assign it a DIP footprint, and save. After that it will appear under "user contributed" parts for everyone.